# HTML Template for Repeating Elements + Unique IDs

Tags: jquery, templates

I've got a workscreen where users can create a page, and as part of that process, can create multiple labels for the page, in different languages. There must be at least one label, and can be up to 10 (currently).

To accomplish this, I've got a template for the language select and value input, with buttons to add and remove labels:

```js
function addLabel(show_eng) {
  var template = $('#label_template').html();

  $('#labels_div').append(template);
}

function removeLabel(remove_btn) {
  $(remove_btn).closest(".label-div").remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="labels_div">
  <div class="width-100 f-left">
    <a id="new_label" class="btn f-right" title="Add a new label">
      <i class="fa-icon-plus"></i>
      <span class="margin-left-5">Label</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script id="label_template" type="text/x-template">
  <cfoutput>
    <div class="width-100 f-left margin-bottom label-div">
      <div class="width-45 f-left">
        <select class="dropdown-field-padding width-94 f-left">
          <option value="0">Select a language....</option>
          <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(languages)#" index="alpha">
            <option value="#languages[alpha].ID.xmltext#">#languages[alpha].Name.xmltext#</option>
          </cfloop>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="width-45 f-left">
        <input class="input-field-padding width-90 f-left" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="width-10 f-left">
        <a class="btn f-right" onclick="removeLabel($(this));" title="Remove label">
          <i class="fa-icon-remove"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfoutput>
</script>
```

The issue that I'm running into is that the validation system we're using requires that each element being validated has an ID (used to position the error message at the correct input).

Is there some javascript/JQuery snippit I can drop into my addLabel function to add unique IDs to the language dropdown and value input field? Or some way I can change the template itself to handle/create an ID?

This is very much a corner case for us, so I'd prefer to not have to install a whole new JS library for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this snipped for numbered IDs:

```
var index = 1;
$('select, input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id',index);
    index++;
});
```

or something like that...